# Onclick on image I need to change the background of li using jquery

Tags: jquery

Onclick on image I need to change the background of li using jquery

LI is not immediate parent so I am not able to use parent() function in jquery

```
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr ui-draggable">  
    <fb:profile-pic height="32" width="32" linked="false" uid="557103888" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" class=" fb_profile_pic_rendered">  
        <img class="" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" title="some name" alt="some name" src="files/t557103228_5135.jpg">  
    </fb:profile-pic> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.closest('li')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

This will give you the first ancestor of the `<img>` that is an `<li>` element.

You could also use [`.parents('li:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/). It uses the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to ensure you only get the first result.

Comment: .parents('li:first') is not working but .closest('li') its working fine.
I used as below

$item.closest('li').css('background-color', 'red');

Thank you Patrick.

Comment: @Elankeeran - You're welcome. :o) Very strange that `.parents()` didn't work. Anyway, glad that `.closest()` panned out for you.

Comment: How to toggle the background color?

Comment: @Elankeeran - The background color of the `<li>`?  If you just want to change the color, you would do: `.closest('li').css('background','purple');` If you thought you were going to toggle it back and forth, I'd probably use a class, and then do `.closest('li').toggleClass("myBackgroundClass")`. This way it will add and remove the class with each click. (Remember to add the class definition to your style sheet.)

Comment: Thank you! but I have many li with inside image onclick on image li will get background color. suppose I clickon other li image that should get background and other should be default color its like switch selection (radio button).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$('img[title="some name"]').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('li.ui-widget-content').css('background', 'green');
});
```

Since the image does not have any `class` or `id` attribute set, the `title` attribute is used instead. In this case any image whose title is set to `some title` for example gets clicked, the background of parent `li` with class `ui-widget-content` is changed using `css` method which is actually found with `closest` function which finds elements back up until specified element is found.

Comment: How to toggle the background color?

Answer (score 0):

It's the grandparent, so `.parent().parent()` then.

Or use `.closest('li')`.